# Problem with Keras model output shape error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I am trying to build a Keras model for my reinforcement learning algorithm, but I am encountering a problem related to an error about an invalid output shape. Here is the code for my build_model function:

```
def build_model(observation_space, action_space):
    # Input for possible_position_map matrix
    possible_position_map_input = Input(shape=observation_space['possible_position_map'].shape, name='possible_position_map_input')
    # Reshape input data to fit Conv2D format
    possible_position_map_reshaped = Reshape((100, 1, 1))(possible_position_map_input)
    # Convolutional layers for processing possible_position_map matrix
    possible_position_map_conv = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 1), activation='relu')(possible_position_map_reshaped)
    possible_position_map_flatten = Flatten()(possible_position_map_conv)
    
    # Input for height_map matrix
    height_map_input = Input(shape=observation_space['height_map'].shape, name='height_map_input')
    # Reshape input data to fit Conv2D format
    height_map_input_reshaped = Reshape((100, 1, 1))(height_map_input)
    # Convolutional layers for processing height_map matrix
    height_map_conv = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 1), activation='relu')(height_map_input_reshaped)
    height_map_flatten = Flatten()(height_map_conv)
    
    # Input for currentBox vector
    current_box_input = Input(shape=observation_space['currentBox'].shape, name='current_box_input')
    current_box_flatten = Flatten()(current_box_input)
    
    # Merge all branches
    merged = Concatenate()([possible_position_map_flatten, height_map_flatten, current_box_flatten])
    
    # Dense layers for action decisions
    dense1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(merged)
    dense2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(dense1)

    # Output layer for discrete actions
    output = Dense(action_space.n, activation='softmax')(dense2)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[possible_position_map_input, height_map_input, current_box_input], outputs=output)
    return model
```

Invocation:

```
env = ENV.env.BinEnv(False, False)

model = ENV.Model.build_model(env.observation_space, env.action_space)

model.summary()

policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, 
              nb_actions=env.action_space.n, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)

dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\konra\.conda\envs\magisterka\Lib\site-packages\rl\agents\dqn.py", line 107, in __init__
    raise ValueError(f'Model output "{model.output}" has invalid shape. DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action, in this case {self.nb_actions}.')
ValueError: Model output "Tensor("dense_2/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 100), dtype=float32)" has invalid shape. DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action, in this case 100.
```

Can someone help me identify the cause of this error and how to fix it?

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to
==================================================================================================
 possible_position_map_inpu  [(None, 100)]                0         []
 t (InputLayer)

 height_map_input (InputLay  [(None, 100)]                0         []
 er)

 reshape (Reshape)           (None, 100, 1, 1)            0         ['possible_position_map_input[
                                                                    0][0]']

 reshape_1 (Reshape)         (None, 100, 1, 1)            0         ['height_map_input[0][0]']

 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 98, 1, 16)            64        ['reshape[0][0]']

 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 98, 1, 16)            64        ['reshape_1[0][0]']

 current_box_input (InputLa  [(None, 3)]                  0         []
 yer)

 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 1568)                 0         ['conv2d[0][0]']

 flatten_1 (Flatten)         (None, 1568)                 0         ['conv2d_1[0][0]']

 flatten_2 (Flatten)         (None, 3)                    0         ['current_box_input[0][0]']

 concatenate (Concatenate)   (None, 3139)                 0         ['flatten[0][0]',
                                                                     'flatten_1[0][0]',
                                                                     'flatten_2[0][0]']

 dense (Dense)               (None, 128)                  401920    ['concatenate[0][0]']

 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 64)                   8256      ['dense[0][0]']

 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 100)                  6500      ['dense_1[0][0]']

==================================================================================================
```

I've tried verifying that the output shape of my model matches the number of actions in my environment (env.action_space.n), and it seems to be correct. I've also double-checked the input shapes and ensured that all layers are connected properly.

entire trace back:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to
==================================================================================================
 x (InputLayer)              [(None, 100)]                0         []

 fx (InputLayer)             [(None, 3)]                  0         []

 theta (InputLayer)          [(None, 100)]                0         []

 dense (Dense)               (None, 64)                   6464      ['x[0][0]']

 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 64)                   256       ['fx[0][0]']

 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 64)                   6464      ['theta[0][0]']

 concatenate (Concatenate)   (None, 192)                  0         ['dense[0][0]',
                                                                     'dense_1[0][0]',
                                                                     'dense_2[0][0]']

 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 64)                   12352     ['concatenate[0][0]']

 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 100)                  6500      ['dense_3[0][0]']

==================================================================================================
Total params: 32036 (125.14 KB)
Trainable params: 32036 (125.14 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Shape of the model output: (?, 100)
Expected shape for DQN: (None, 100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\konra\.conda\envs\magisterka\Lib\site-packages\keyboard\_generic.py", line 22, in invoke_handlers
    if handler(event):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\konra\.conda\envs\magisterka\Lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 474, in <lambda>
    return hook(lambda e: e.event_type == KEY_UP or callback(e), suppress=suppress)
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\studia\ISA\magisterka\Magisterka\main.py", line 328, in obsluz_zdarzenie
    keras()
  File "E:\studia\ISA\magisterka\Magisterka\main.py", line 275, in keras
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, nb_actions=nb_actions, memory=memory, nb_steps_warmup=2000,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\konra\.conda\envs\magisterka\Lib\site-packages\rl\agents\dqn.py", line 107, in __init__
    raise ValueError(f'Model output "{model.output}" has invalid shape. DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action, in this case {self.nb_actions}.')
ValueError: Model output "Tensor("dense_4/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 100), dtype=float32)" has invalid shape. DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action, in this case 100.
```

Comment: Please add the entire traceback

Comment: edited and added at the bottom

Comment: Could you also print `env.action_space.n`? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, for late answer. I resolved the problem with writing own DQNAgent. As soon as I came home i will send the env.action_space.n to check if it was a problem.